# Assign Class to All Elements of Same Bound Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a scatter plot and a table. Each circle in the scatter plot has a corresponding row in the table. When I apply classes to the circles for CSS purposes, I also want to have that same class be assigned to the corresponding table row. They have the same data value, but are appended to separate elements.

Here is my circle class event:

```
my_circles.each(function(d,i) {
    if (my_bool===true) {
        d3.select(this).classed('selected',true);
        //d3.selectAll('tr').filter(d===???) 
    }
});
```

I was trying to use a filter to select only the table rows of matching d value, but it didn't quite work out, I didn't know how to finish the line. Which got me thinking, maybe there is a better way, like the post title, assign classes to all elements bound to the same data.

If you have another solution aside from any of my ideas, that would be fine too.

Comment: Your code makes little sense to me. If the boolean is true, all circle elements will have the same class (`selected`).

Comment: I just put that portion of the code in the post because it seemed like the most relevant. The actual function itself is way too lengthy for the post, but  I'll summarize what's happening for clarity. Its actually not a global bool, it takes the cx and cy of the circles and compares it against user defined values, which results in a bool. So ultimately, the user decides how many circles are classed `(selected)` Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That being the case, use the same `each` for the tr selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution will be to check in the `.classed()` method for the `tr` selection, if the data bound to that `tr` matches the one for the selected circle.

```
my_circles.each(function(d,i) {
    if (my_bool===true) {
        d3.select(this).classed("selected",true);
        d3.selectAll('tr')
          .classed("selected", trData => d === trData);  // Set class if data matches
    }
});
```

This, however, is a bit clumsy and may be time-consuming because it will iterate over all `tr`s each time this code is called. In case this is in an outer loop for handling multiple selected circles—as mentioned in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245585/assign-class-to-all-elements-of-same-bound-data#comment71651302_42246327)—things will get even worse.

---

#### D3 v4

For a slim approach I would prefer using D3's [local variables](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local-variables), which are new to v4, to store the references between circles and table rows. This will require just a one-time setup which will depend on the rest of your code, but might go somewhat along the following lines:

```
// One-time setup
var tableRows = d3.local();
my_circles.each(function(d) {
  var row = d3.selectAll("tr").filter(trData => d === trData);
  tableRows.set(this, row);  // Store row reference for this circle
});
```

This creates a new local variable `tableRows` which is used to store the reference to the corresponding table row for each circle. Later on you are then able to retrieve the reference to the row without the need for further iterations.

```
my_circles.each(function(d,i) {
    if (my_bool===true) {
        d3.select(this).classed('selected',true);
        tableRows.get(this).classed("selected", true);  // Use local variable to get row
    }
});
```

---

#### D3 v3

If you are not yet using D3 there are, of course, other ways to achieve the same thing. Personally, I would prefer using a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) to store the references. Because the API of the `WeakMap` also features get and set methods similar to `d3.local`, all you need to do is to change the line creating the local reference store while keeping the rest of the above code as is:

```
// var tableRows = d3.local();
var tableRows = new WeakMap();   // use a WeakMap to hold the references
```

Comment: that's exactly what I am looking to do, but I am working with v3, and I have some scripts that are dependent on v3 as well, so I'm currently seeing if I can adapt your answer to v3. Would a native javascript `object` work? `var tableRows = {}`

Comment: @ArashHowaida Although an object may also work, I, personally, prefer using a `WeakMap`. This, however, will not work in IE <11, in which case you might be forced to resort to the object approach instead. There are many possible solutions when keeping in mind that the main focus should be on avoiding repetitive iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataIndex for this purpose. Here is a code snippet for the same.

```js
var data = ["A", "B", "C"];

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var container = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", 500)
  .attr("width", 500);

var my_circles = container.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("name", function(d, i) {
    return "circle" + i
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return (i + 1) * 50
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return (i + 1) * 50
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  });

container.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("name", function(d, i) {
    return "rect" + i
  })
  .attr("width", 15)
  .attr("height", 15)
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 50 + 200
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return (i + 1) * 50
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i)
  });

my_circles.each(function(d, i) {
  d3.select(this).classed("selected" + i, true);
  container.selectAll("[name=rect" + i + "]").classed("selected" + i, true);
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think I follow your index technique. With regards to assigning a class though, I'm a little unclear. Suppose there are 20 circles, and then through some event listeners the user has made 3 circles `(selected)`, how do I use the index to class the corresponding table rows, or in your case rects, to be `(selected)` too?

Comment: In that case also, `my_circles` will only contain the 20 circles which were generated using the data array and the corresponding indexes will work as expected.